# Laravel has one through not returning correctly. always returning the first ID

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a table that looks like this

```
ContractorDocuments        Documents                      Documents_Category
user_id                     id                                 id
documents_id               documents__category_id              name
```

I tried the following in my ContractorDocuments Model however it is always returning the first Document Category only.

```
public function Documents_Category() {
return $this->hasOneThrough(Documents_Category::class, Documents::class, 'documents__category_id', 'id', 'documents_id','documents__category_id');
}
```

- documents__category_id == foreign key on Documents Table
- id =  foreign key on owners table(Documents_Category)
- documents_id =   local key on owners table(ContractorDocuments)
- documents__category_id = local key on Documents table

Would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `ContractorDocuments` to `Documents_Category`, you don't need `hasOneThrough` relationship since `ContractorDocuments` can only have one `Documents_Category` through `belongsTo()`.

```
// ContractorDocuments model

public function documents()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Documents::class, 'documents_id');
}
```

And

```
// Documents model

public function documents_category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Documents_Category::class, 'documents__category_id');
}
```

You can just call

```
$contractorDocuments->documents->documents_category;
```